# Poetry could not find a pyproject.toml file in /repo/python/home/manal/smallsat/apps/pl-cfdp/test/transfer_tool or its parents

Tags: python, pyproject.toml

This error popped up out of nowhere, I have my pyproject.toml file within the directory it is looking in. I created a fresh .toml file as well. I am not sure what else to do?

```
Poetry could not find a pyproject.toml file in /repo/python/home/manal/smallsat/apps/pl-cfdp/test/transfer_tool or its parents
```

I have tried moving the python file to another folder and making initiating a poetry init there as well and I seem to be having the same problem.

[What my folder looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZJN1.png)

Comment: Please post your exact command and tell us where you run it.

Comment: my exact command is "python3 transferring.py" and I run it from the transfer_tool directory.

Comment: Please run `poetry init` and tell us what the response is.

Comment: If the error pops out of a python-source-file, we probably need to see some of that too. This is not reproducible as it is. Can you provide a stacktrace?